# Are they obfuscated of C# code?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Are these lines of codes obfuscated (C#) ?

```
HWND__* ptr = <Module>.FindWindowW(null, (char*)(&<Module>.??_C@_19HAIJKKDJ@?$AA7?$AA5?$AA5?$AA4?$AA?$AA@));        
<Module>.SendNotifyMessageW(ptr, 1024u, (uint)num, 0);
```

If yes, is there a software to de-obfuscate them ?

Full method (codes are decomplied by ILSpy decomplier):

```
// My7554_Launcher.Form1
protected unsafe override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    IntPtr wParam = m.WParam;
    IntPtr lParam = m.LParam;
    if (m.Msg == 1024)
    {
        if (wParam.ToInt32() == 1)
        {
            <Module>.LicenseServices.UnlockExecute();
            <Module>.LicenseServices.CloseSession();
            base.Close();
        }
        if (wParam.ToInt32() == 3 || wParam.ToInt32() == 4 || wParam.ToInt32() == 5)
        {
            if (<Module>.LicenseServices.LockExecute() == null)
            {
                base.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                int num;
                if (wParam.ToInt32() == 3)
                {
                    num = this.EGLiDecode1(lParam.ToInt32());
                }
                if (wParam.ToInt32() == 4)
                {
                    num = this.EGLiDecode2(lParam.ToInt32());
                }
                if (wParam.ToInt32() == 5)
                {
                    num = this.EGLiDecode3(lParam.ToInt32());
                }
                HWND__* ptr = <Module>.FindWindowW(null, (char*)(&<Module>.??_C@_19HAIJKKDJ@?$AA7?$AA5?$AA5?$AA4?$AA?$AA@));
                <Module>.SendNotifyMessageW(ptr, 1024u, (uint)num, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

p/s:
Although there are some comments mention that it isn't written in C# but I found somewhere it's very close to C#, for instance :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ComponentResourceManager manager = null;
    manager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    base.SuspendLayout();
    SizeF ef = new SizeF(6f, 13f);
    base.AutoScaleDimensions = ef;
    base.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
    Color window = SystemColors.Window;
    this.BackColor = window;
    this.BackgroundImage = (Image) manager.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage");
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
    Size size = new Size(0x28c, 0x138);
    base.ClientSize = size;
    base.ControlBox = false;
    base.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    base.Icon = (Icon) manager.GetObject("$this.Icon");
    base.Name = "Form1";
    base.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Text = "Launcher";
    Color white = Color.White;
    base.TransparencyKey = white;
    base.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    base.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Comment: That looks much closer to the output of standard C++/CLI than obfuscated C# code.

Comment: @JaredPar: It's just got some compiler-generated names in it, that aren't legal identifiers in C#, C++/CLI, VB.NET, or anything else I know of.  Or maybe they were generated by the disassembler.  There may be some syntax that isn't commonly seen in C#, because it's in the `unsafe` subset, but `uint` is a C# type keyword and not found in C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes, codes are decomplied by ILSpy decomplier

Comment: @JatSing - No it isn't obfuscated as much as *mangled* that is just how ILSpy decompiles references to unmanaged code (think PInvoke).

Comment: I found somewhere it's very close to C#, please see update in my question.

Comment: @JatSing The "very close to C#" is so simple that it'd decompile to VB.NET as "very close to VB.NET", as F# as "very close to F#" and so on. Then converting an extremely simple piece of code to a given language the converter finds it, well, very simple. That example demonstrates nothing.

Comment: Indeed, for that matter, `$this` isn't something that screams `C#` so if anything you've posted an example with something that suggests it wasn't C#

Answer (score 3):

That isn't valid C#.

That might be what some disassembler/decompiler shows when you ask it to generate C# from an assembly originally written in a language that supports free functions (C++/CLI does, I think VB.NET does also).

Perhaps that decompiler also provides help locating the string literal.

The message number was substituted during the original compilation, if you want to convert it to a `WM_`* constant, you'll have to look it up yourself.  The compiler has no way of knowing which of many many constants equal to 1024u was in the original source.  For a .NET programmer, you might refer to [this list of Window Messages](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.WindowsMessages) instead of the SDK header files.

Overall, you're going to have better luck fixing this code by hand.

Comment: `1024` is `0x400` which is `WM_USER`

Comment: VB.NET does not support free functions. They have to be in a `Module`, which is essentially a C# `static class` with an extra attribute applied.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: But not a member of a class... and `<Module>` is exactly what's showing up in the disassembled code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be compiler generated code, probably from a mixed mode assembly (C++.Net). However, there is a little chance string encryption was applied. I would decompile other methods and check if they contain strings (something like manager.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")). In case you can find strings in other methods the code is surely not obfuscated.